# WebStorm "Argument type X is not assignable to parameter type Y"

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2016.1.3 with an Angular 2 project and in the following code snippet I get an error in the component description (see title):

```
import {ImageCheckboxComponent}     from "./imageCheckbox.component";
import {HHMovieComponent}           from "./hhMovie/hhMovie.component";
import {HHTopBarComponent}          from "./hhTopBar/hhTopBar.component";

//noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
@Component
({
    selector: "my-app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    directives: [ImageCheckboxComponent, HHMovieComponent, HHTopBarComponent]
})
```

If I comment the `directives` line out the error disappears.
It also disappears when I enable the WebStorm internal typescript compiler.
However, I don't want that because I have everything set up in gulp, which is faster and more efficient than the WebStorm handling of typescript.

Is there any way to disable that?
I tried the `noinspection` annotation in the comment right above `@Component` but it made no difference.

Comment: Try WebStorm 2016.2 EAP build -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/06/webstorm-2016-2-eap-162-844/